# Applying .animate() to a row added using .after()

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-after

So I currently use the following:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "file.php",
    success: function(html) {
        $("#tableRow").after(html);
    }
});
```

which neatly adds a new row (or rows) to an existing table.
file.php returns:

```
<tr><td>stuff</td></tr>
```

I can add a single row at a time.
I'm trying to animate just the newly added row like:

```
$("#tableRow").after(html).animate({ backgroundColor: "#bce4b4" }, "fast")
```

but that highlights the row I'm adding the new row after.  I can't get it to apply to just that new row.  How can I do that?

**UPDATE**:

Based on the answers given I put this together:
http://jsfiddle.net/jreljac/5ctpc/3/ where I do the following:

```
$("<tr><td>2 1</td><td>2 2</td></tr>").insertAfter("#tableRow").animate({
    backgroundColor: "#bce4b4"
}, "slow");
```

(I replaced what file.php will give with text") and that does not seem to work.  It creates the row but does not animate.  Am I missing something simple?

Comment: Yep, you forgot to check the box next to 'jQuery UI 1.8.16' ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do what you want:

```
$(html).insertAfter('#tableRow').animate({ backgroundColor: "#bce4b4" }, "fast")
```

Although 'html' is just a string, you can still wrap it in `$()` to turn it into a jQuery object.

Answer (score 5):

User `insertAfter` instead.  It will then animate the correct row.

```
$(html).insertAfter("#tableRow").animate(...
```

Comment: like this : `$(html).insertAfter("#tableRow").animate(...)`

Comment: Yup, thanks.  Realized that wasn't so clear and added the example right as you did.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [insertAfter()](http://api.jquery.com/insertAfter/) instead

```
$(html).insertAfter('#tableRow').animate({ backgroundColor: "#bce4b4" }, "fast");
```